# Animated left and right arrow in css

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to  create a loading page and I thought while the page loads i'd give a little instruction to how the page worked.

See this image

[image]

Firstly is this possible in css, I think not but i'm amazed at what you can do in css now and secondly, can it be animated slightly maybe a shimmer of light going from left to right and back again?

Comment: Yes this can be done in css, the arrows themselves would need to be pngs or svgs though.. or maybe some kind of wing ding font would have this..

Comment: Check out [SpinKit](http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/).

Comment: Thank you, at least I know now so I can figure out how.